# All users not shown in user report generated for a site using SP Designer

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

While generating user report for a site using SP Designer, details are shown for only few users. Rest are merged together in 'All Others' category.

**Is there a way to get report which shows all users individually?**

Comment: How are you creating this report in SPD?

Comment: which version of SP Designer (2007/2010) & SharePoint (2007/2010/Found./Server) are you using?

Comment: @DavidLozzi: Opening the site in SP Designer, then from menu, we select Site->Reports->Usage

Comment: @sbc111: Both SP Designer and SharePoint are 2007 version.